# Zend framework admin module and other modules

Tags: zend-framework, module, reusability

I want to build a CMS based on Zend Framework for my needs which has **admin** module with authentication and other modules (**pages, users, news**) which can be used as plugin modules based on the appliaction needs.

I want every module to have specific frontend and backend code, so that it could be accessed like e.g. http://localhost/mycms/pages/view/5 to view a certain page from the **pages** module by calling **Pages** controller, **view** action. The backend for every plugin needs to be tied to the admin and require authentication, it could be accessed like http://localhost/mycms/admin/pages/add.

The problem is that the solution I found involves removing default routes and writing custom routing for every controller action inside the plugin modules like:

```
  $router->removeDefaultRoutes();

  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
      'admin/pages/add',
      array(
       'module' => 'pages', 
       'controller' => 'Pages',          
       'action' => 'add'
      )
  );

  $router->addRoute('pages_pages_add', $route);

  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
      'pages/view/(\d+)',
      array(
       'module' => 'pages', 
       'controller' => 'Pages',          
       'action' => 'view'
      ),
      array(
       '1' => 'page_id'
      )
  ); 

  $router->addRoute('pages_pages_view', $route);
```

Do you have any ideas how I can avoid this custom routing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Front Controller Plugins, they may give you more flexibility...

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

```
class Controller_Plugin_Foo extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request )
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        ...
    }
}
```